# store data in a csv file using the curl command

Tags: linux, bash, csv, curl, leshan

following this image:

[image: leshan-server]

through a bash script invoked from the terminal I should store the values ​​of "latitude, longitude, timestamp and speed" in a csv file. However, these values ​​update every 1 second, which is why I wrote the following scrip bash to stop when necessary:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true;

do curl -s -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://172.17.0.2:8080/api/clients/giammi-VirtualBox/6/0 >> myresponse.csv

sleep 1s

done
```

the problem is that in this way it returns the csv file as follows:

[image: csv]

the parameters of my interest are: 0,1,5,6 which correspond to latitude, longitude, timestamp and speed, so what I would like is a representation like:

```
0,1,5,6
xxx,xxx,xxx,xxx
yyy,yyy,yyy,yyy
```

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32960857/how-to-convert-arbitrary-simple-json-to-csv-using-jq) ... you can't just save JSON output and hope for it to be well-formed CSV.

Comment: Please include a small representative sample of what your curl command returns as text, in the post - not as a screenshot of a spreadsheet program.

Comment: Use jq to get the values you need and output them as csv

Comment: how can i use jq? can you give an example please?

Comment: Post an extract of the json returned by from the curl command.

Comment: Perhaps see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65338470/json-lines-jsonl-generator-to-csv-format/65338582

Comment: This seems like the wrong way to extract this data. Can't you have the client write these values directly to a file instead of trying to scrape it off the web interface?

Comment: @Z4-tier The OP might not have control of the app's code.