# JSON function output to CSV file - Python

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv, google-maps

I have been trying to use a function from **populartimes** library that returns a json file that includes information regarding a place using this resource link https://github.com/m-wrzr/populartimes.

```
import populartimes
import pandas as pd
import json
import csv

r = populartimes.get_id("API KEY","ChIJSYuuSx9awokRyrrOFTGg0GY")
display(r)
```

The output of the function is in json:

```
{'id': 'ChIJSYuuSx9awokRyrrOFTGg0GY',
 'name': 'Gran Morsi',
 'address': '22 Warren St, New York, NY 10007, USA',
 'types': ['restaurant', 'food', 'point_of_interest', 'establishment'],
 'coordinates': {'lat': 40.714315, 'lng': -74.007766},
 'rating': 4.4,
 'rating_n': 407,
 'international_phone_number': '+1 212-577-2725',
 'populartimes': [{'name': 'Monday',
   'data': [0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0]},
  {'name': 'Tuesday',
   'data': [0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    30,
    40,
    50,
    54,
    48,
    32,
    0]},
  {'name': 'Wednesday',
   'data': [0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    31,
    43,
    52,
    53,
    45,
    32,
    0]},
  {'name': 'Thursday',
   'data': [0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    49,
    69,
    80,
    78,
    62,
    39,
    0]},
  {'name': 'Friday',
   'data': [0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    49,
    58,
    67,
    71,
    67,
    52,
    0]},
  {'name': 'Saturday',
   'data': [0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    63,
    77,
    92,
    100,
    92,
    69,
    0]},
  {'name': 'Sunday',
   'data': [0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0]}],
 'time_spent': [90, 210]}
```

I wish to convert the json to csv file but the usual pandas library is not working properly on the output and returning different errors. I have troubleshooted using different methods.

If I use

```
df = pd.DataFrame(r)
```

it returns ValueError "Mixing dicts with non-Series may lead to ambiguous ordering."

If I use

```
data = json.dumps(r)
df = pd.DataFrame(data[populartimes])
```

it returns TypeError: string indices must be integers

If I use

```
data = json.loads(r)
```

It returns TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict

Essentially what I am trying to do is write this json to a csv file in which the headers in json are the columns in the csv file and the values will be under the columns. I wish to make it possible for multiple json entries to the csv files after I am able to write this single json to a csv. Can anyone help in writing this json to a csv file?

Comment: Can you share the errors you are experiencing.   As it stands, all we have to work with is "something is broken".

Comment: Do you want to append the output to an existing CSV file or do you want to return a "string" that could be a CSV file line? I'm not sure what you're tying to do.

Comment: I want to convert the output to a csv file like pandas_to.csv creates a new csv file of a dataframe.

Comment: I have updated the errors in the description

Comment: There is no simple straightforward way to format arbitrary JSON as CSV. Maybe see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65338470/json-lines-jsonl-generator-to-csv-format

Answer (score 0):

try using this code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json (r'Path where the JSON file is saved\File Name.json')
df.to_csv (r'Path where the new CSV file will be stored\New File Name.csv', index = None)
```

Comment: The json is not in any file. The function returns a json output.